# How to Get A Item Source Proerty Of XamComboEditor in Code Behind in Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am struggling with one issue . I have a `XamComboEditor` and i want to know MVVM source property of this in code behind in Run Time.

```
<ig:XamComboEditor x:Name="Country"   EmptyText="Select ..." DisplayMemberPath="CountryName" SelectedValuePath="CountryCode" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="Country_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataCountry}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEdit,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
             Grid.Row="0"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="40" />
```

---

```
var be = Country.GetBindingExpression(getComboBox.ItemsSource);
if (be != null && be.ParentBinding != null)
{
    sourceProperty = be.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
    if (sourceProperty.Contains('.'))
    {
        var spliteed = sourceProperty.Split('.');
        sourceProperty = spliteed[1];
    }
}
```

How to get MVVM Property Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetBindingExpression` method expects a `DependencyProperty`:

```
var be = Country.GetBindingExpression(XamComboEditor.ItemsSourceProperty);
if (be != null && be.ParentBinding != null)
...
```